# When appending unique values in array to an excel range, highlight the cell if it is a duplicate

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of values `result` that I got from a REST API call - `result = [1,2,3,4,5]` and they are parsed in as variant in the `AppendUnique` function.

##### What I want to do:

`AppendUnique` function appends unique values from a growing `result` array to a range in excel. **I want to add a new feature to `AppendUnique`, where the repeated values in the `result` array will be highlighted in the excel cell.**

##### Explanation on my current code:

**In the beginning**

I input each value in the array `result` to populate cells from `A1` to `A5` (the range is dynamic, based on the number of values in the array, so might not be `A5` all the time).

> So, **if the range `(A1-A100)` is empty**, we populate the cells normally.

> ^ this part is completed

**As the result array grows**

Since the result will increase as we run the Macro again, for example, 15 minutes later the `result` may become `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

> So, **if the range `(A1-A5)` is not empty**, we append the array's additional items at the back of the cell range, if they do not appear in the range (meaning they are additional ones)

> ^ this part is completed

The result may also contain duplicates, for example, 30 minutes later, the `result` may become  `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3]`, where 3 is the duplicate.

> If there is duplicate - 3, the cell `A3` (where we populated 3) needs to be highlighted.

> ^ **this question is about this part**

##### My current code:

```
Sub AppendUnique( _
        Arr() As Variant, _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal FirstCellAddress As String, _
        Optional ByVal OverWrite As Boolean = False)
   
    ' Write the data from the source range to the source array ('sData').
    ' Reference the first destination cell ('fCell').

    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(FirstCellAddress)
    
    Dim sData() As Variant, srCount As Long
    
    With fCell
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
            srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
            If srCount = 1 Then
                ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = .Value
            Else
                sData = .Resize(srCount).Value
            End If
            If Not OverWrite Then Set fCell = lCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
            
    ' Write the unique data from the source array to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount: dict(CStr(sData(sr, 1))) = Empty: Next sr
    
    Erase sData
    
    ' Define the destination array ('dData').
    
    Dim lb As Long: lb = LBound(Arr)
    Dim ub As Long: ub = UBound(Arr)
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To ub - lb + 1, 1 To 1)
                 
    ' Check the values from the given array ('Arr') against the values
    ' in the dictionary and write the non-matches to the destination array.
    
    Dim dr As Long, c As Long, cString As String
                 
    For c = lb To ub
        cString = CStr(Arr(c))
        If Len(cString) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            If Not dict.Exists(cString) Then ' is not in the dictionary
                dict(cString) = Empty ' prevent dupes from the given array
                dr = dr + 1
                dData(dr, 1) = cString
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    
    If dr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No new values found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
    
    fCell.Resize(dr).Value = dData
    If OverWrite Then ' clear below
        fCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - fCell.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    End If
        
    ' Inform.
        
    MsgBox "Data appended.", vbInformation
         
End Sub
```

I initially thought maybe I can do something under the line - `If Len(cString) > 0 Then`, to add `If dict. Exists(cstring) Then`, highlight the cell by doing something like `interior.color = vbYellow`.

However, I realised that in my current code, the products are appended altogether after checking the repeated items, so I am not exactly sure how to highlight the cell of repeated value, since we are not looping over the appended range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you not use conditional formatting?

Comment: the highlight needs to be done automatically when we detect duplicates when appending values in array. So I think conditional formatting shouldnt work

Comment: Don't think I understand. What do you mean by automatically? You can't "highlight" values in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dictionary value to store a reference to the relevant row. The complication is to differentiate between existing keys from the sheet and those added from the array. For the Overwrite mode the values from the sheet become obsolete. I have used a concatenated string of the row offset and either ";sht" or ";arr". It is easy to separate the 2 values with split().
To identify duplicate in the array I have added another dictionary - `dupl`.

```vb
Sub AppendUnique( _
        Arr() As Variant, _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal FirstCellAddress As String, _
        Optional ByVal OverWrite As Boolean = False)

    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim fCell As Range, lCell As Range, tcell As Range
    Dim sData() As Variant, srCount As Long
     
    ' Write the data from the source range to the source array ('sData').
    ' Reference the first destination cell ('fCell').
    Set fCell = ws.Range(FirstCellAddress)
    If Len(fCell) = 0 Then
        srCount = 0
        ' target cell for appending new items
        Set tcell = fCell
        fCell.ClearFormats
    Else
        Set lCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp)
        srCount = lCell.Row - fCell.Row + 1
        If srCount > 1 Then
            sData = fCell.Resize(srCount).Value2
        Else
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1):
            sData(1, 1) = fCell.Value2
        End If
        ' clear any existing coloring
        fCell.Resize(srCount).ClearFormats
        
        ' target cell for appending new items
        Set tcell = lCell.Offset(1)
    End If
                
    ' Write the unique data from the source array to a dictionary.
    Dim dict As Object, sr As Long, r As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    r = 0 ' row offset
    If srCount > 0 Then
        For sr = 1 To UBound(sData)
            dict(CStr(sData(sr, 1))) = r & ";sht" ' fcell row offset +1
            r = r + 1
        Next sr
    End If
    
    ' reset target cell
    If OverWrite Then
        Set tcell = fCell
        r = 0
    End If
    
    ' Define the destination array ('dData').
    Dim lb As Long, ub As Long
    Dim dr As Long, c As Long, cString As String
    Dim dData() As Variant:
    lb = LBound(Arr)
    ub = UBound(Arr)
    ReDim dData(1 To ub - lb + 1, 1 To 1)
                 
    ' Check the values in Arr
    ' against the values in the dictionary and
    ' write the non-matches to the destination array.
    Dim dupl As Object, k
    Set dupl = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For c = lb To ub
        ' dictionary key
        k = CStr(Arr(c))
        If Len(k) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            If Not dict.Exists(k) Then
               ' is not in the dictionary
               ' prevent dupes from the given array
                dict(k) = r & ";arr ' store fcell offset"
                r = r + 1
                dr = dr + 1
                dData(dr, 1) = k
            End If
        
             ' check for duplicates in arr
            If dupl.Exists(k) Then
                dupl(k) = dupl(k) + 1
            Else
                dupl.Add k, 1
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    
     ' clear existing data
    If OverWrite And srCount > 0 And dr > 0 Then
        fCell.Resize(srCount).Clear
    End If
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array
    ' to the destination range.
    If dr > 0 Then
        tcell.Resize(dr).Value = dData
    End If
       
    ' highligh if duplicate
    Dim ar
    For Each k In dupl.keys
        If dupl(k) > 1 Then
            ar = Split(dict(k), ";")
            r = ar(0)
            If dr > 0 And OverWrite And ar(1) = "sht" Then
                ' do nothing as row information is useless
                ' for existing value with overwrite
            Else
                fCell.Offset(r).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    If dr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No new values found.", vbExclamation
    Else
        ' Inform.
        MsgBox dr & " Data rows appended.", vbInformation
    End If         
End Sub
```